# How to customize library icon in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, icons, windows-libraries

How do I change the icons in the library folder? I used a simple trick from [howtogeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14101/add-my-dropbox-to-your-windows-7-start-menu/) to change the location of a start menu item.
What I did was to change the music library shortcut to a www directory shortcut since I frequently open the directory.
How do I change the small music icon?
[image]

Comment: FYI, you can create your own custom libraries without having to do anything to the existing ones. Some libraries, like the music library, are used by the system in certain specific ways (such as by windows media player), so it may be better to not touch them if you don't have to, and create your own.

Comment: tried that, its just that you can really place the custom library in the start menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3011-libraries-icons-change.html

This will change the main icon, I'm not sure about the little icon on the left

Answer (score 0):

http://deskmodder.deviantart.com/art/library-icon-changer-142792517

This changes even icons at the side